# How can i count view_number from a model filtered by session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

i was coding a feature about view_number(view count) of Blog.

It's worked when i reload page, however i want count view_number based on session. Maybe it like [Usage #8](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) in this gem

Any solution for this? Thanks you for reading

```rb
class Home::UpdateBlogViewNumberWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'blogs'

  def perform(*args)
    blog_id = args.first
    viewer = Blog.find_by_id(blog_id)

    if viewer.present?
      view_number = viewer.view_number.to_i + 1
      viewer.update_attribute(:view_number, view_number)
    end
  end
end
```

and my controller

```rb
class Home::BlogsController < Home::BaseController
  #...
  def show
    update_blog_view_number
  end

  private

  def update_blog_view_number
    Home::UpdateBlogViewNumberWorker.perform_async(@blog.id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by  'based on session' , is it the current user session etc ?

Comment: It can be current_user, current_host, guest

Answer (score 0):

IDK what means your Blog model, if returns Users, or returns Posts, or return a Blog, like multi tenant blog app maybe. I will assume that returns Posts.

If you want control who view something, like the gem that you sent the link, you will need a table to match between session_hash, ip, or user_id and blog_id. Then you should ask to this table if the match exist for this post, if exist don't do anything but if doesn't exist will increase the counter.

Consider for better scalability add an index in the matches table by your user identifier (session, ip, id) and another in the blog_id.